# C++ data type with custom range [0, 64]?

Tags: c++, struct, custom-data-type

I looked for similar questions, but didn't find my answer.

Basically, I need to declare/define a variable that has a specific range from 0 to including 64.
Do I use an enum? A struct? Can I do that when declaring a variable?
I want to use it in a struct.

Of course I could write some if/else check, but there has to be a simpler way without making an array[64].

Comment: Is 64 included or not? If not, you could use a bitfield.

Comment: There are fixed-width [integer types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).

Comment: Both 0 and 64 are included. If it helps, it's supposed to represent inventory stacks in Minecraft. Max stack size is 64. 0 is empty.

Comment: It depends on how you want to use it and why you want it? For example is it to save space or to detect out of range errors?

Answer (score 2):

If you only need a constrained integer you could just check for the range in the constructor. Like so:

```
#include <stdexcept>

template<int max>
class ConstrInt {
public:
   ConstrInt(int val) {
      if (val > max)
         throw std::out_of_range("");
      m_val = val; 
   }

   int value() const {
      return m_val;
   }
private:
   int m_val;
};



int main(){
   ConstrInt<64> a{1};
   auto aa = a.value();
   ConstrInt<64> b{65};  // exception for > 64
}
```

Comment: Actually I was hoping I could use a char (smaller) and restrict it to [0, 64].

Comment: Can't I define an enum with a range from 0 to including 64 without manually spelling out every value?

Comment: @Kampfkeksgeschwader: Enums have a minimum range which is already rounded up to just below the next power of two (i.e. 127), and you also miss the arithmetic operations of an integer type.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I use an enum?

I dont't see how it would be useful.

> A struct?

If you want to define a custom datatype, then want to define a class (structs are classes).

> Can I do that when declaring a variable?

You can define variables of custom data types if that's what you mean.

> Of course I could write some if/else check, but there has to be a simpler way without making an array[64].

There is no need to make an array just to check whether a value is within a range. Here is an example check:

```
if (x >= 0 && x <= 64)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a class carrying an `unsigned char` and make it wrap around just like the built-in unsigned integer types does, so that `0 - 1` results in `64` and that `64 + 1` results in  `0`.

Example:

```
template<unsigned End = 64>
class usmall {
public:
    // implicit conversion constructor, making sure the value is in the range [0, End]
    usmall(unsigned char v = 0) : data(v % (End + 1)) {}

    // implicit user defined conversion operator
    operator unsigned char () const { return data; }

    // pre increment and decrement operators
    usmall& operator++() { if(data==End) data = 0; else ++data; return *this; }
    usmall& operator--() { if(data==0) data = End; else --data; return *this; }

    // post increment and decrement operators
    usmall operator++(int) { usmall rv(*this); ++*this; return rv; }
    usmall operator--(int) { usmall rv(*this); --*this; return rv; }

    // common arithmetic operators
    usmall& operator+=(const usmall& rhs) {
        data = (data + rhs.data) % (End + 1);
        return *this;
    }
    
    usmall& operator-=(const usmall& rhs) {
        if(data < rhs.data) data += (End + 1);
        data -= rhs.data;
        return *this;
    }

    usmall& operator*=(const usmall& rhs) {
        data = (data * rhs.data) % (End + 1);
        return *this;
    }
    
    usmall& operator/=(const usmall& rhs) {
        data /= rhs.data;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    unsigned char data;
};

// free arithmetic functions
template<unsigned End>
auto operator+(const usmall<End>& lhs, const usmall<End>& rhs) {
    usmall rv(lhs);
    rv += rhs;
    return rv;
}

template<unsigned End>
auto operator-(const usmall<End>& lhs, const usmall<End>& rhs) {
    usmall rv(lhs);
    rv -= rhs;
    return rv;
}

template<unsigned End>
auto operator*(const usmall<End>& lhs, const usmall<End>& rhs) {
    usmall rv(lhs);
    rv *= rhs;
    return rv;
}

template<unsigned End>
auto operator/(const usmall<End>& lhs, const usmall<End>& rhs) {
    usmall rv(lhs);
    rv /= rhs;
    return rv;
}
```

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    usmall foo = 3;
    usmall bar = 30;
    usmall baz = foo * bar;
    std::cout << static_cast<unsigned>(baz) << '\n'; // prints 25
}
```