Create Clamped Datatype
I want to create a c++ datatype that will always clamp it's value between 0.0 and 360.0. Other than that, it should behave exactly as a double. I would use it like this:
degree my_num1 = 3.5;   //my_num1 will equal 3.5

degree my_num2 = 400.8;   //my_num2 will equal 360.0

degree my_num3 = -5.1;   //my_num3 will equal 0.0

my_num3 = my_num2 - my_num1;   //my_num3 will equal 356.5

I have tried defining a template class, but I couldn't figure out how to make it work. typedef seems too limited, and I don't think struct will work either. I know that I can make a class and use getters and setters, but I really don't want to do that. Sorry if the answer is obvious, I am pretty new to c++. Also, I am using c++17.
edit:
I was trying something like this:
template <class T>
class degree{
   private:
    double number;

   public:
    degree(double n) : number(n){}

    void operator=(double new_value){
        //clamping code...
        number = new_value;
    }
};

I really didn't know what to do. Also, I don't think this is a duplicate question, as I don't want to use getters and setters.

You make a class with a bunch of overloaded arithmetic operators. Whether or not it needs to be a template depends on whether you want to support different underlying types (or only double), but otherwise doesn't affect anything.

"I have tried defining a template class" - You don't need a class template if you only want to mimic double. Please show your attempt in a [mre].

@TedLyngmo I'll try and add an example of what I was trying.

@Invader88 Note that Ted already wrote an appropriate answer for that problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65578376/1413395

A reference to std::clamp seems relevant.

@πάνταῥεῖ I will try and adapt his answer to my needs.
